# Reverse contents of a Queue

Tags: java, queue, reverse

I have to reverse the contents of a queue, but currently I am experiencing problems with my reverseQueue method. Whenever I print out it prints out the array content twice. If anyone could explain what I am doing wrong will be helpful.

Code:

```
public static void reverseQueue (Queue Q){
    for (int i = Q.size() -1; i>=0; i--){
        int temp = (int) Q.dequeue();
        Q.enqueue(temp);
        System.out.print(temp+" ");
    }
    }
```

Size method:

```
public int size(){
    return count;
}
```

Queue

```
public class Queue{
private int QUEUE_SIZE = 5;
private Object[] items;
private int front, back, count;

public Queue() {
    items = new Object[QUEUE_SIZE];
    front = 0;
    back = QUEUE_SIZE -1;
    count =0;
}
```

Example Output:

I am going to reverse my queue.

My queue is as follows:
20 30 40 50 20 30 40 50

Comment: What is the output you are getting? You should print the queue after the `reverseQueue` method. That will give you the output

Comment: Trace the logic through in your head or on paper with some simpler cases, for example `Q.size() == 2`. It should be evident what the issue is.

Comment: What type is Queue? It's not java.util.Queue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a copy into a list, reverse and re-population

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Queue<Integer> foo = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(foo);
    reverseQueue(foo);
    System.out.println(foo);
}

public static <T> void reverseQueue(Queue<T> q) {
    List<T> copy = new ArrayList<>(q);
    Collections.reverse(copy);
    q.clear();
    q.addAll(copy);
}
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Great, but I can only use conventional methods from a queue such as dequeue, enqueue, size, etc. Is their a way in my array to delete all the elements and then start from the end of the queue and reinsert every element back so it is reverse?

Comment: @Alan Please clarify which implementation of "Queue" you are using java.util.Queue does not have dequeue() and enqueue() methods... Also are you looking for general solution or is this a assignment with artificial constraints on your solution?